# Making use of Include function Entity Framework but returns null on included object

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework

I want to make use of Entity frameworks including functions to bring back my users with there apiKeys, but currently only the user gets returned and none of the keys, the relationship is one to many. a user can have many ApiKeys. but an ApiKey can only have one user.

I have tried specifically stating the Foreign key and also without it, but leading to the same result. of returning the user object but with no ApiKeys.

I am not sure if I should otherwise use join?
all data presented is test data.

[Sql statement being generated by code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmFy.png)

Unfortunately, I can't embed images yet, here are image links.

Can someone please assist?

[ApiData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t1Eq.png)

[UserData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhxKa.png)

[Include method called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UMqL.png)

[User and Apikey models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwzYZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be more successful in asking questions, it's better not to [post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Also, please carefully select a tag corresponding with the EF version you're using.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for your response, It seems that there was a problem where entity framework was conflicting with the PostgreEntityframework installation.
the solution was to only have the Designers on the base entityCore, and the Postgre designer as well as the base for postGre. 
the ones I used not fixed the problem: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design, Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL